# best approach to convert html to pdf in angular 8 as device independent

Tags: jspdf, html2canvas, angular8

i am using html2canvas & jspdf in angular 7/8 for generate html content to pdf. but while working on responsive web app on mobile view the html content gets changes as it is responsive and thats why it generate canvas of dom element as responsive so my question is what is best approach to download common view as pdf (which means device view independent) so i can download same pdf on any type of device